# Error to install the "R programing course" in my Elementary OS Freya or Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: r, rstudio

I am trying intall  "R programing course" from the package  Swirl with the function `install_from_swirl("R Programming").When I typed the function it returns this error

```
Error en handle_setopt(h, ...) : no se pudo encontrar la función "anyNA"
```

How I can solve this problem?

I think that problem it's caused for the package Curl.

My R version is 3.0.2 (2013-09-25)

Comment: What version of R are you using?  I believe anyNA is part of base R.

Comment: Update R? `anyNA` has been introduced in a relatively recent version (about one year ago if I remember correctly).

Comment: No,I install R three months ago. My version of is R version 3.0.2 (2013-09-25).

Comment: @user3716340 Yeah that dates to 2013.  anyNA was added in 3.1. You need to upgrade.